# Can I link windows 10 and Ubuntu over Ethernet?

Tags: networking, windows, ethernet

I have 2 very cheap desktop computers that both don't have internet adapters I got a adapter for my windows 10 desktop but I don't want to get another for my Ubuntu computer is there a way that I can connect a Ethernet cable between to both to share the WiFi. I have looked tried to connect them and create a bridge and share the connection but it did not work I am new to this so I could have just done it wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If the adapter is in Windows, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Ask on [su].

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You want to share a cable (ethernet) connection through a wireless (wifi) connection? Do you want to use an internet router, an ethernet switch or just a cross-over cable? And Zacharee1 is right, this is Ubuntu-only site.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to get both machines on the same local network (LAN). Once you have that, you can either define one as the [default gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) of the other. Or you can just connect both machines to your LAN and use the central networking device as gateway for both.

But to create a LAN, it probably won't be enough to just put a cable between them. You'd need some networking device that routes and organizes the data traffic, something like a switch, a hub or a router. Many ISPs offer networking devices (mostly all-in-one router) by default.

Comment: "_be enough to just put a cable between them_" It should be enough, but in my experience, it's quite hard to actually get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it, is using a router. Or connect both pc using ethernet cable and activate internet connection sharing in windows 10.